# Why is CreateElement() a member function of XmlDocument class?

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument, createelement

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();         
XmlElement elem = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Elem");
xmlDoc.AppendChild(elem);
```

`AppendChild()` is doing some changes to the object referred by xmldoc.... it makes sense it is a member function

`CreateElement()` which looks more like a common function to all the objects.... why is it a member function() ?

Comment: I'd suppose that this is because internally some stuff in the freshly created element is initialized that's specific to the given XML document. That would not be possible if it was static - or you'd have to pass the respective `XmlDocument` instance. By the way: You could peek into the source code of the framework and see for yourself what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CreateElement` method probably creates a new `XmlElement` using the `XmlElement` [constuctor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlelement.xmlelement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which requires an `XmlDocument` as one of the constructor params.

Comment: Why guess or couch this in terms of "probably" when you can [view the source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/Xml/System/Xml/Dom/XmlDocument.cs#890)

Comment: Then the next question is: Why does the XmlElement class needs the XmlDocument parameter? In the end, is's a design decision that there shouldn't be a XmlElement without a OwnerDocument. Why this descision was made can probably only be answered by the designer of this class.

Comment: This is more about the DOM specification than it is about the author's implementation decisions.  For instance: it is assumed that all child nodes of a node belong to the same document; a list of child nodes is a live list, it reflects changes; default attribute values depend on the document; EDIT: entities.  So, you can't just pick an element from one document and move it to another document, you must clone it.

Comment: What is the XmlElement constructor doing with the XmlDocument exactly?

Comment: @krishna222 You can look at the actual source of `XmlElement` from @Damien_The_Unbeliever above.  But, in general, letting the element know about the document that it belongs to lets the element know about it's parent node, and about all it's siblings, ancestors, etc.